# Should we explicitly release / kill threads in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

This is regarding JMeter

I have a thread group where number of threads is 100. I get response for all the 100 requests in say 3 minutes. However when I generate html report from the .jtl file, it still shows around 50 threads as active even after 6 to 7 minutes.

I was expecting that the active threads would also die out once the response is received. Should we kill/release threads or do we have a similar option in JMeter which I am missing. Can someone advise please.

Comment: Try disabling your listeners in test

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 1 loop in Thread Group - each thread (virtual user) should be terminated once it finishes execution of all the [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), assuming you don't have i.e. [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) or [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which may (and will) "hold" the threads alive.

[image]

Also make sure to follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article, in particular:

1. Run your test in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Remove all the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) from the Test plan

If the issue persists - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and take the [thread dump](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html) to identify what exactly JMeter threads are doing.